# Change the x-axes levels with a list of specific numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following:
`p = [2;3; 4; 6; 8;11;16;23;32; 45;64;91;128;181;256;362]
up = [4.00;3.66; 3.500; 3.50; 3.37; 3.27; 3.18; 3.13;3.09;3.04; 3.00;2.97;2.94;2.90;2.89;2.87];
down = [1.50; 2.00;2.00;2.16;2.25;2.27;2.37;2.43;2.50;2.55;2.57;2.61;2.64;2.67;2.68;2.70];
fill([p;flipud(p)],[up;flipud(down)],'--b')`

This draw me the x-coordinate: `0,50,100,150,200,250...400` but i want the x-coordinate labels with p values=`(2,3,4,6,8,11,16,23,32,45,64,91,128,181,256,362)` 
Please help.

Comment: Please provide the [minimal data that produces your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !!

Comment: i edited my questions with all informations.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Matlab are you using?

---

> **Note:** Starting in R2014b, you can use dot notation to set properties. If you are using an earlier release, use the set function instead, such as `set(ax,'YTick',[-1 -0.5 0 0.5 1])`.

---

```
% For R2014a and earlier:
% set(ax,'XTickLabel',{'-3pi','-2pi','-pi','0','pi','2pi','3pi'})
% set(ax,'YTickLabel',{'min = -1','-0.5','0','0.5','max = 1'})
```

[See documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html)

---

My code below:

```
clear
clc
close all
p = [2;3; 4; 6; 8;11;16;23;32; 45;64;91;128;181;256;362];
up = [4.00;3.66; 3.500; 3.50; 3.37; 3.27; 3.18; 3.13;3.09;3.04; 3.00;2.97;2.94;2.90;2.89;2.87];
down = [1.50; 2.00;2.00;2.16;2.25;2.27;2.37;2.43;2.50;2.55;2.57;2.61;2.64;2.67;2.68;2.70];
fill([p;flipud(p)],[up;flipud(down)],'--b');
labels={'2' '3' '4' '6' '8' '11' '16' '23' '32' '45' '64' '91' '128' '181' '256' '362'};
set(gca,'Xtick',linspace(p(1), p(end), length(labels)),'XTickLabel',labels)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I have edited my question to solve my problem accordingly.

Comment: the graph is not right because it does not change with the labels. 
Can i draw the x-axis logarithmically with the above data? meaning can i apply `semilogx(..)` function over here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the length of XTickLabel and XTick must match.

See following code sample:

```
x = 2:64;
y = sin(x/10);

plot(x, y);

XTickLabel = {'2' '3' '4' '6' '8' '11' '16' '23' '32' '45' '64'};

ax = gca;
ax.XTick = linspace(x(1), x(end), length(XTickLabel));
ax.XTickLabel = XTickLabel;
```

[image]

As **GeekCristiano** mentioned,

> The above sample requires Matlab R2014b and above.

For versions before Matlab R2014b use the following example:

```
x = 2:64;
y = sin(x/10);

plot(x, y);

XTickLabel = {'2' '3' '4' '6' '8' '11' '16' '23' '32' '45' '64'};

ax = gca;
set(ax, 'XTick', linspace(x(1), x(end), length(XTickLabel)));
set(ax, 'XTickLabel', XTickLabel);
```

Comment: `set(..)` works in my computer but your code does not work to solve my problem correctly. sorry! i edited the question with more information.